# Continue button does not work at checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento-1.4

I have a shop that was working normally but now if the person is at checkout and have not register for registering and when it fills the billing information, the button "continue" has no action, and there is no javascript error. The site is http://livraria.senado.gov.br/checkout/onepage/

Does anyone know what can be?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there *are* javascript errors, which can be seen in your browser developer console. The AJAX requests are being routed through `http://localhost/` which is not going to be accepted by your browser.

[image]

Comment: He always worked with this error! What is a JavaScript that before had to fill address by postcode. But I will try to see if it solves the problem. It could be something else if this does not work? thanks

Comment: That "localhost" domain isn't coming from the aether ;-)

Comment: hehehehe .... already removed the onblur action of the field, but is still shooting, I am trying to locate this script to remove it because it does not know where he is. thanks

Comment: I found, I'll see if they will correct the record. thanks

Comment: I made the withdrawal of the script that was calling, yet it leaves the "Cep" field is still experiencing the same error. Know where I can find it? thanks

Comment: @tvieira that is a new question :-)